# Valid Oauth redirect uri's

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mobile, ios9

Im making an app and Im integrating Facebook's login. On the app page in the settings its asking for a valid oauth redirect uri.

My url scheme is fb followed by the numbers e.g. fb123456798 .

How do I make an uri based off that ? I need the uri so my app gets called back after user authentication.

Thanks !

Comment: `fb123456798://something` will work if you have the scheme set up in your app correctly.

Comment: thanks i tried it but i keep getting the sorry something went wrong error